# Обработчик не видит смены класса jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Есть простенький код:

```
$('.like').on("click", function(){
            console.log("click_l");
            $(this).addClass('unlike');
});
$('.unlike').on("click",function(){
            console.log("click_u");
            $(this).addClass('like');
});
<button class="btn btn-default card_body_like like_div unlike"><div></div></button>
```

Как видно изначально класс unlike (для него есть свой стиль, подсветка, как и в like) Проблема в том, что постоянно выводит в консоль *click_u*, то есть даже когда класс *unlike* пропал, а вместо него поставил *like* - оно принимает эту кнопку как элемент с классом *unlike*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `$('.like').on("click" ...` выполняется один раз и прикрепляет обработчик клика к элементам выборки `$('.like')`, то есть элементам с классом `"like"` на момент выполнения этого кода.

```js
$('.container').on("click", '.like,.unlike', function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('like'))
    console.log("click_l");
  if ($(this).hasClass('unlike'))
    console.log("click_u");

  $(this).toggleClass('unlike like');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default card_body_like like_div unlike"><div>Click</div></button>
</div>
```

Comment: ну ок, как вариант. Но в чем причина того, что у меня не вышло? почему не работает?

Comment: @shumik_UA Вы прочитали три строчки в начале ответа? В них что-то непонятно?

Comment: а, вижу, не обновил